# sails.sockets.join is not working

Tags: sockets, sails.js

I migrated sails from v0.10 to v0.11 and also I have followed the migration guide and did the following,

1. sails generate sails.io.js --force.
2. beforeConnect and afterConnect function.

The following issues I am facing,

The below function is not executing,so I am not able to add any users to the room

```
  sails.sockets.join(req, roomName, function(err) {
  /*code here*/
  });
```

beforeConnect function in sockets.js is not at all calling.

```
beforeConnect: function(handshake, cb) {
     // `true` allows the connection
     console.log("connected");
     return cb(null, true);

     // (`false` would reject the connection)
   },
```

Comment: After some Workaround, I was able to find that sails.sockets.join works fine in 0.11.5 version.